# Context: Error if columns and placefigure are in the same document

Tags: context

If I use `\startcolumns ... \stopcolumns` and `\placefigure[right]` in the same document I get the error message `\placefigure: Undefined control sequence`.

```
\starttext
\startbodymatter
Text
\startcolumns[n=2,rule=on]
Text
\column
Text
\stopcolumns
\placefigure[right,nonumber]{Text}{\externalfigure[Picture.jpg]}
\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

If I delete the lines from `\startcolums` to `\stopcolumns` it is fine. On the other hand if I delete the location `right` in the `\placefigure` command it is OK too. The combination of columns and figure location `right` causes an error. Can someone help me please?

This is the content of the log-file:

```
open source     > level 1, order 1, name '/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-yes.mkiv'
system          > 
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2018.04.04 00:51 MKIV beta  fmt: 2020.1.3  int: english/english
system          > 
system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > level 2, order 2, name '/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv'
close source    > level 2, order 2, name '/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv'
system          > files > jobname 'Test2', input './Test2', result 'Test2'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > level 2, order 3, name '/home/oliver/Context/Test2.tex'
fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (second stage)
fonts           > 'fallback modern-designsize rm 12pt' is loaded
structures      > begin of sectionblock 'bodypart'
columns         > balanced in '1' step(s)
floatblocks     > '1' placed (right)


tex error       > tex error on line 9 in file /home/oliver/Context/Test2.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<argument> \d_strc_floats_margin 

\strc_floats_mark_as_free ...d_free_offset_left #2
                                                  \d_free_offset_right #3\d_...
\strc_floats_mark_par_as_free ...sides_bottomskip 
                                                  \or \strc_floats_mark_as_f...
\page_sides_push_float_inline ...mark_par_as_free 
                                                  \ifcase \c_page_sides_floa...
\page_sides_place_float ...des_place_float_normal 
                                                  \fi \par \kern -\d_page_si...
\page_sides_handle_float ...age_sides_place_float 
                                                  \page_sides_check_floats_r...
...
l.9 ...nonumber]{Text}{\externalfigure[Picture.jpg]}                                           

 1     \starttext
 2     \startbodymatter
 3     Text
 4     \startcolumns[n=2,rule=on]
 5     Text
 6     \column
 7     Text
 8     \stopcolumns
 9 >>  \placefigure[right,nonumber]{Text}{\externalfigure[Picture.jpg]}
10     \stopbodymatter
11     \stoptext
12
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the `log` file because I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I added the log file now. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into the log file you can see your ConTeXt version is from **April 4th 2018** and a day earlier the name of the internal register `\d_strc_floats_margin` was changed to `\d_page_sides_margin`.

```
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2018.04.04 00:51 MKIV beta  fmt: 2020.1.3  int: english/english
```

While the register name was changed in the two files `strc-flt.mkvi` and `page-sid.mkiv` the file `anch-bck.mkvi` was forgotten and got the fixed a week later.

You can see the problem in this was of the log file where TeX complains about the non existing command:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 9 in file /home/oliver/Context/Test2.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<argument> \d_strc_floats_margin
```

The only way to fix this is to install a newer version of ConTeXt where this is fixed.